# How to make an effective electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, speakers

I am making a speaker with some neodymium magnets and about 3m of copper (insulated) cable. How would I configure this to make it loudest/best electromagnet?

Comment: What does "best" mean? Just loudest? Highest fidelity? Most efficient? Lowest cost?

Answer (score 3):

I'd aim to maximize the force between windings and magnet - this should impart maximum force onto the speaker diaphragm. Magnetic Force exerted by a solenoid is: -

\$\dfrac{(F_M)^2 \mu_0 A}{2 g^2}\$

- Where Fm is magneto motive force in ampere-turns
- A is cross sectional area of solenoid or coil
- g is the gap between solenoid and poles of iron (in your case the magnet)
- \$\mu_0\$ is 4\$\pi \times 10^{-7}\$

It's not 100% clear to me how g would be measured because normally is would be the gap at the end of the solenoid in the direction towards a piece of iron. Nevertheless, the clues in the equation above tell you that the cross sectional area of the coil and the number of turns will play a dominant role in getting more force onto the speaker cone/diaphragm.

If it were me I'd just buy a speaker!

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot more to a good speaker than just a electromagnet.  In fact, there isn't really just a electromagnet in most speakers.  They are usually a permanent magnet with a movable coil around it.  Current thru the coil causes a force on it, which moves it, which moves the speaker cone attached to it.  This is tricky since the coil has to have electrical connections but still move easily, and it has to be light.

For just making a hack to learn or demonstrate with, you can wrap the wire around the permanent magnet without needing it to move.  Current thru the wire will add and subtract from the fixed magnetic field of the magnet.  Some sort of thin magnetic membrane in proximity to the magnet will then feel the varying magnetic field and be moved by it.  It won't be very efficient, but it should work well enough as a physics demonstration.

If you want a efficient high-fidelity speaker, go buy one.